# How to download iPad Mini simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I want to test my application on iPad mini screen in Xcode 8.2, but I could not find the simulator for the same.

I have also tried to add simulator  **Hardware > Device > click bottom add menu** but here I do not see any option to download the iPad mini simulator.
[image: There is no option for iPad mini (image here)]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

By popular demand, Xcode now includes the iPad mini Simulator. It is not created by default, but you can use the Xcode Devices & Simulators window or `xcrun simctl` from the command line to create one.

For example, to create an iPad mini 4 simulator with Xcode 11.2:

`xcrun simctl create "iPad mini 4" com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-4 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-2`

Comment: IPad mini screen size is 7.9 inch so there is any way to set screen size in simulator?

Comment: The resolution is identical between the mini and 9.7" iPad so there is no difference between their behavior.

Comment: many time my client facing some design issue in 7.9" and i have 9.7" inch display . so any solution ?

Comment: We always match the number of pixels for the device. At 100% Scale (in the Window menu) we make those virtual pixels match your Mac's DPI. In no case do we try to make the on-screen Simulator have the same physical device size.

Comment: @russbishop I guess this isn't accurate now there's a "Physical Size" scaling option?

Comment: So does the iPad Air or Air 2 has same resolution as iPad Mini?

Comment: Is there no chance to simulate the 7,9'' of the iPad mini for testing purposes? My app has a split view, and for iPad mini it seems to be too small, so I need to work on it.

Comment: @Daniel check my answer. You can do this on the latest Xcode.

Comment: Year 2019 Akshar should be the answer

Comment: I updated my answer; by popular demand we now ship an iPad mini device type.

Comment: Note: you must now change the very last character of the command from `2` to `3`, like so: `xcrun simctl create "iPad mini 4" com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-4 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3`
SO won't let me make a single-character edit to the answer.

Comment: Now works `xcrun simctl create "iPad mini 4" com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-4 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4`

Answer (score 29):

I don't know about the earlier releases but you can do this on Xcode 10.2.1(or later)

Select `Add Additional Simulators...` from the active scheme:

[image]

Then press `+` to create new Simulator and select `iPad mini` in Device Type:

[image]

Comment: Year 2019, this is the answer!

Comment: Thanks! still usefull in 2021

Comment: In 2023 Xcode version 15.0.1 it says unknown runtime