# Run The App in iPad Mini 4 Configurations

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, ipad-mini

I have developed IOS app for iPod touch and now I want to test My app in 
iPAD Mini4 configurations because, one of my client told app was crashing in iPad Mini4.I tried in Xcode simulators but there is no iPAD Mini 4 and i don't have the device also.I have tried to download the iPad mini4 simulators in my Xcode but option for iPad mini4 is not available.Please tell how to test my app in iPad Mini4

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use the iPad simulator.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154600/how-to-download-ipad-mini-simulator) link for reference

Comment: it helped me, thanks!
 But still not providing "iPad mini 4" simulator is a source of confusion...